# jquery easytabs - how to make a tab a pop-up link?

Tags: jquery, html

This is my navigation and I use easytabs jquery script:

```
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div class="navigation">
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li><a href="#home">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#cv" target="_blank">CV</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#research">Research</a></li>
                <li><a href="#teaching">Teaching</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /Navigation -->
```

I want to change #cv tab into a pdf pop-up link. I have tried to use inline jscript, did not work. Any solutions?

[thats the link you can see it in action](http://www.eminli.net/test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your easyTabs initialisation to:

```
$content.easytabs({
        tabs                :"> .navigation > ul > li:not(.external)",
        animate             : true,
        updateHash          : true,
        animationSpeed      :'normal',
    });
```

Then add a class of `external` to your CV link:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#home">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#cv" target="_blank" class="external">CV</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#research">Research</a></li>
    <li><a href="#teaching">Teaching</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So, I did as per you suggested. However, once I change href="link.pdf" I see all the tabs in the same page (locally). Now, going to try it in the server to see if it is different which I doubt.