# external link with jquery cycle

Tags: jquery, cycle, jquery-cycle

I want to add external link to one of the navigation buttons with jquery cycle. Lets assume there are 5 buttons and I would like to make one of them external link. Any tips?

```
    $('#content').cycle({
        fx:     'scrollUp',
        speed:  'slow',
        timeout: 0,
        pager:  '#nav',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
            // return sel string for existing anchor
            return '#nav li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';
        }           
    });
```

and here's what I found, please see comment

```
    $('#content').click(function() { 
    $('#nav li:eq(2) a').trigger('click'); 
    **return '<a href="' + el.src + '">' + (i+1) + '</a>';** // this should be it but how do I implement so both triggers work accordingly?
});
```

and html outline:

```
<div class="menu">                          
                            <ul id="nav">
                                <li class="home"><a href="#home" title="home" >Home</a></li>
                                <li class="about"><a href="http://www.dot.net/Resume.pdf" title="about" class="external">About</a></li>
                                <li class="networks"><a href="#networks" title="networks">Networks</a></li>
                                <li class="last contact"><a href="#contact" title="contact">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <br class="spacer"/>
                        </div>
```

Comment: sorry, 4 lines from the bottom are added afterwards, I should separate them, but that should not be there. I need to control only #content (#nav).

Comment: suggest you just create your own pager and events and not do it in the `pagerAnchorBuilder`

Comment: not very talented in jquery

Comment: Thats fine. Clicking anywhere on #content will trigger a click event on '#nav li:eq(2) a'.. What does the '#nav li:eq(2) a' event handler do? Actually the correct question is what event should trigger/cause the external link to be added? Is it during pagination? Could you share the HTML outline of your page.

Comment: yep sure, let me clarify really quick. last four lines are another founding and may not be relevant. But the return part works well if I replace it with  return '#nav li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a'; but then other tabs do not work.

Comment: @makalele Sorry I don't quite get the problem.. Could you reply to my previous two questions? Also you may consider deleting this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687988/jquery-external-link

Comment: Hi @Kent Pawar, please have a look at this question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521922/jquery-easytabs-how-to-make-a-tab-a-pop-up-link - I would like to do same with jquery cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (which == "resume"){     
      $('#nav li:eq(2) a').trigger('click'); 
    return '<a href="' + el.src + '" >' + (i+1) + '</a>';
```

that was my solution for now.